# Why I can not move Logout button to right side

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to move logout button to `Right` side

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Odjava</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" class="nav-link">Prijava</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" class="nav-link">Registracija</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

I try something like adding `text-right`

```
<li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block text-right">
                <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Odjava</button>
                </form>
            </li>
```

Also I try add

```
style="text-align:right;




<li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block text-right" style="text-align:right;">
                <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Odjava</button>
                </form>
            </li>
```

[image]

Also something like this I also try

```
<button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark text-right">Odjava</button>
```

Also using `float: right` doesn't work

```
 <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark float-right">Odjava</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bootstrap navbar. You need to add ml-auto on what you want to align on the right. ml-auto will align to the left.

This is an example of a username and logout on the right from the _loginPartial.

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link " asp-area="Test" asp-page="/Home/Index" title="Manage">@UserManager.GetUserName(User)</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Test" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
            <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

[image]
Here is the documentation if you want to review.

- [bootstrap auto-margins docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#auto-margins)
- [bootstrap navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/)

If you override the ul with a float attribute you can get it to work as noted in @mj1313 response. It will result in shifting the ul to the right on the collapsed state of the navbar, so if you want to have this aligned to the right on collapse then you can use it.

**ml-auto collapsed**

[image]

**float:right collapsed**

[image: float right collapsed state]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
  <li class="nav-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, it is look like that somewhere is blocking this class

Comment: Then please try this.
<ul class="navbar-nav" style="float: right;">
  <li class="nav-item"></li>
</ul>

Comment: No, still the same problem. It is look like that `AdminLTE` template use some `css` class which doesn't allow me to make changes

Comment: Please try <ul class="navbar-nav" style="float: right !important;"> <li class="nav-item"></li> </ul>
Please focus that the style is in <ul>, not <li>

Comment: Yes, I add style in `<ul>` but nothing happened, again same problem

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="float: right"` to the form tag.

```
<form style="float: right" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Odjava</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to just add `text-align:right` to `.form-inline` class

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/7cx9w1n3/